# ServletOutputStream closes prematurely

Tags: servlets, download

I wrote a servlet to download a file. it works well for some files, but for others the os closes prematurely, and I end up downloading a blank file.

```
        File file = new File(fileName);

        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName );
        resp.setDateHeader("Expires",0);
        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        resp.setHeader("Pragma", "public");

        resp.setContentLength((int) file.length());
        resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
        ServletOutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
        byte[] bufferData = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;
        while((read = fis.read(bufferData))!= -1){
            System.out.println("read " + read + " chars");
            os.write(bufferData, 0, read);
        }
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        fis.close();
```

when I debug, I can see it trying to write the first buffer worth of data into os, then on the browser side, the download dialog pops up with a blank file. in the servlet, I get a IOClosed on the next buffer write.

I tried using IOUtils.copy(fis, resp.getOutputStream());

get the same error.

any reason certain type of file data can force os to close prematurely? can I protect against it?

Comment: You don't seem to encode your binary output files. I suggest you look at [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) from Apache. Also, you should not close the `OutputStream`, just call `flush()`. Why two `Content-Disposition` headers? Finally, you're setting the `content-type` to `text/plain`.

Comment: it is not a binary file. it is in fact text/plain, and actually does contain some Base64 data. I solved the problem by using PrintWriter and BufferReader.readLine.

Comment: You should just call flush() on your OutputStream, sometimes client(s) disconnect.

Comment: I do call os.flush(). see the code. when this error occurs, the execution jumps to catch clause, and never reaches the flush() line. like I said, problem was solved by using PrintWriter instead.